# dict object is not callable,

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding a python "script" that transfers from Octal to Binary now I encountered this:

`'dict' object is not callable`

this is my script:

```
    OctalBinary1 = {
          "0" : "000",
          "1" : "001",
          "2" : "010",
          "3" : "011",
          "4" : "100",
          "5" : "101",
          "6" : "110",
          "7" : "111"
}

def toBinaryOctal(x):
          counter = 0
          sum_var = ""
          fin_var = ""
          if len(x) % 3 == 0:
                  for i in x:
                            counter += 1
                            sum_var += str(i)
                            if counter == 1:
                               for x , y in OctalBinary1():
                                        if x == sum_var:
                                                  print ("ok")
                                                  fin_var += OctalBinary1[x]
toBinaryOctal("123")
```

Comment: You should write `OctalBinary1.items()` in the second `for` loop and btw, nice Christmas tree.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory, no? A dictionary isn't an object you can call as a function.

Comment: Python already has the facilities for the conversion you seek, try `bin(int("123", 8))` or `"{:b}".format(int("123", 8))` if you want more control over the format. You can find the format string syntax specification [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: I know, but as school homework I have to do it by myself, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to iterate through keys and values of a dict would be:

```
for x, y in OctalBinary1.items():
    if x == sum_var:
        print ("ok")
        fin_var += OctalBinary1[x]
```